# Error when adding package accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I'm trying to add a package to a meteor project using meteorite using the command:

```
mrt add accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown
```

And the command shows me this error:

```
   tag: https://github.com/erobit/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown.git#v0.1.5

fs.js:730
  return binding.symlink(preprocessSymlinkDestination(destination, type),
                 ^
Error: ENOTDIR, not a directory '/Users/arturcarvalho/projects/effinlist/.meteor/packages/accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown'
    at Object.fs.symlinkSync (fs.js:730:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/dependencies/package.js:129:10
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:75:15
    at GitSource._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:120:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:73:18
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:89:5
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:216:5
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:635:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
```

If I run mrt list after this, it shows me the following error:

```
While building package `accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown`:
error: no such package: 'accounts-urls'
```

I can't uninstall the package and tried to reinstall meteorite but no luck. Could somebody help me with this? I'm using Max OS X.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you on Meteor 0.6.5?

if so it's because the package hasn't been updated yet to work with that version, there was a lot of api changes in the way you format your package.js file and most packages on meteorite haven't been updated to adhere to the new style yet so they all break.

**Recommendation:**

1 Use this command to downgrade and wait a few weeks until atmosphere packages get corrected

"The way to downgrade is:

$ meteor update --release 0.6.4.1

... but that won't actually undo the other change that updating your 
app to 0.6.5 did.  So you'll also want to edit your ".meteor/packages" 
file and remove the line "standard-app-packages". "

2 Send a PR to the package creator with an updated package.js file adhering to the api rules listed here

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md

File that needs to be updated:

https://github.com/erobit/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown/blob/master/package.js

Comment: Should be that because I did the update not long before. I was just trying this but I can't connect to atmosphere for some reason. It was working fine yesterday. I can't access atmosphere.meteor.com so maybe it's related. Going to try later.

Comment: atmosphere.meteor.com server is down currently but they aren't related, it's because of an API change in 0.6.5 that needs to be fixed by the package creator.

Comment: Yes I know,  I was just commenting in case someone was having the same problem with the update while atmosphere was down. It's working now, Thank you very much flylib! Going to send a message to erobit.

Answer (score 1):

The package has been updated on atmosphere to support the latest meteor release v0.6.5. If you are running latest meteor, you should be able to simply remove and re-add the package.

mrt remove accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown

mrt add accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown

Note: Refer to the readme on the github project page at the url below, as I have updated the installation instructions with more details.

https://github.com/erobit/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Can you try add 'accounts-urls' first?