# meteor > error: no such package: 'accounts-urls'

Tags: meteor, meteorite

Running latest meteor 0.6.5 i got this error:

Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!

=> Errors while scanning packages:

While building package `accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown`:
error: no such package: 'accounts-urls'

Any help appreciated, thnx

Answer (score 5):

it's because your on 0.6.5 and the package hasn't been updated yet to work with that, there was a lot of api changes in the way you format your package.js file and most packages on meteorite haven't been updated to adhere to the new style yet so they all break.

**Recommendation:**

1 Use this command to downgrade and wait a few weeks until atmosphere packages get corrected

"The way to downgrade is:

$ meteor update --release 0.6.4.1

... but that won't actually undo the other change that updating your 
app to 0.6.5 did.  So you'll also want to edit your ".meteor/packages" 
file and remove the line "standard-app-packages". "

2 Send a PR to the package creator with an updated package.js file adhering to the api rules listed here

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md

File that needs to be updated:

https://github.com/erobit/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown/blob/master/package.js

Answer (score 1):

What command did you run before you got the error? If you ran `meteor add accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown`, that won't work.

[`accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown`](https://github.com/erobit/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown) is not part of the official packages repository, but it is part of [Atmosphere](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/).

You have to install the unofficial package manager, [Meteorite](http://oortcloud.github.io/meteorite/) based on the instructions on the webpage, then you can run `mrt add accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown`

EDIT: There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259469/error-when-adding-package-accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown) that is more clear, and you may want to follow this question or confirm that your commands and errors are the same

Answer (score 0):

The package has been updated on atmosphere to support the latest meteor release v0.6.5. If you are running latest meteor, you should be able to simply remove and re-add the package.

mrt remove accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown

mrt add accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown

Note: Refer to the readme on the github project page at the url below, as I have updated the installation instructions with more details.

https://github.com/erobit/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown/blob/master/README.md