# How do you check which version of Meteor you are running?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I am having a similar problem as described here: 
[meteor > error: no such package: 'accounts-urls'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264145/meteor-error-no-such-package-accounts-urls)

To fix this issue it looks like I have to downgrade my version of Meteorite to get 'accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown' to work.

But first I want to check which version of Meteor I am currently running.

How can I do this? I am running Meteor on a mac with terminal.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

## There are 2 versions

### 1. Global tool version of meteor command

Find version by:

```
meteor --version # CAUTION this will auto update your meteor release !!!!!
```

### 2. Project version of meteor

A project stays at the meteor version which it was created with unless manually upgraded. Find this by running:

```
cat .meteor/release
```

Comment: you are right. That's funny, I always cat .meteor/release when I need pinned version :D

Comment: Worth noting that running `meteor --version` while inside a project will show the `.meteor/release` version, even if you have a newer global tool installed.

Comment: Why does running "meteor --version" first download the newest version of meteor-tool ?

Answer (score 21):

There are two places where you should check your Meteor version.

There is a main Meteor tool, installed to your home folder: `/Users/nearpoint/.meteor`. It has auto-updater and it keeps copies of Meteor for different versions installed.

Another place is your project's folder. `project/.meteor/release` contains version of Meteor *this* project is using. Even if your main Meteor tool updated, it will still use the pinned version for your project, so backward incompatible changes will *not* break unless you want it.

To update main Mteor tool (usually it auto-updates but if it doesn't) just run `curl https://install.meteor.com | sh`.

To update version for your project run in your project's folder:

```
meteor update
```

to update to the latest release or

```
meteor update --release 0.6.4.1
```

if you want to upgrade (or downgrade) to the specific release. Now if you look at `.meteor/release` file in your project, it will change to new pinned release.

Comment: Thanks I used meteor update --release 0.6.4.1 to downgrade and now the 'mrt add acounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown' does not give an error anymore! Thanks

Comment: I am glad it helped you! New release (0.6.5) has new backward incompatible changes to packages, you want packages maintainers to update their packages (it's not that hard, btw) before you migrate to 0.6.5

Answer (score 6):

Incase you want to check the version of a running release load up the javascript console and check

```
Meteor.release
```

(This is while its running - Sometimes it can give blank if the app was deployed with meteorite)

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this is to open up your **Javascript console** in the browser and type:

`console.log(Meteor);`

This is very useful for me as I'm running Ubuntu on a Chromebook so I don't need to stop my local server to check which version I'm currently running.

Please note the server **does** need to be running (`localhost:3000`) for this command to work.

Answer (score 4):

I just used

```
meteor --version
```

in nitrous.io and it updated Meteor to 0.9.0. This is NOT a command to merely check version.

Answer (score 4):

`meteor show meteor` has interesting output. This is what I got on my Mac terminal:

```
$ meteor show meteor
Package: meteor@1.1.10                        
Maintainers: mdg                              
Exports: Meteor                               

This is an internal Meteor package.           

Recent versions:                              
  1.1.5   March 18th, 2015                    
  1.1.6   April 1st, 2015
  1.1.7   September 22nd, 2015
  1.1.9   September 29th, 2015
  1.1.10  October 27th, 2015    installed

Older and pre-release versions of meteor have been hidden. To see all 73 versions, run 'meteor show --show-all meteor'.
```

Comment: This seemed promising except it doesn't seem to correspond to the "meteor version" I was looking for.  For meteor 1.5.1 this shows `meteor@1.7.1`.